# Correct way to seed MongoDB with references via mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three schemas, one which references two others:

**userSchema**

```
{ name: String }
```

**postSchema**

```
{ content: String }
```

**commentSchema**

```
{ 
  content: String,
  user: { ObjectID, ref: 'User' },
  post: { ObjectID, ref: 'Post' }
}
```

How can I seed this database in a sane, scalable way? Even using bluebird promises it quickly becomes a nightmare to write.

My attempt so far involves multiple nested promises and is very hard to maintain:

```
User
.create([{ name: 'alice' }])
.then(() => {
    return Post.create([{ content: 'foo' }])
})
.then(() => {
  User.find().then(users => {
    Post.find().then(posts => {
      // `users` isn't even *available* here!
      Comment.create({ content: 'bar', user: users[0], post: posts[0] })
    })
  })
})
```

This is clearly not the correct way of doing this. What am I missing?

Comment: I've seen [this plugin](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/mongoose-seeder). Is this the answer to spare my sanity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about bluebird, but the nodejs Promise.all should do the job:

```
Promise.all([
    User.create([{ name: 'alice' }]),
    Post.create([{ content: 'foo' }])
]).then(([users, posts]) => {
    const comments = [
        { content: 'bar', user: users[0], post: posts[0] }
    ];    
    return Comment.create(comments);
})
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. Can you then chain an additional `.then` which will wait until the Comments are created?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to seed database with automatically references, use [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose).
This is the easiest seeder for you to use. You don't need to write any program files, but only data files. And [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose) handles smart references for you. And by the way, I'm the author and maintainer of this package.

Comment: This looks good. You might want to mention that you're the author of this tool. (That's not a problem, but it's worth mentioning!)

Answer (score 0):

## **Try this it will work fine:**

> *Note:* Node Promise.all will make sure that the both query is executed properly and then return the result in Array:[Users, Posts],
> If you get any error during execution of any query, it will be handle by catch block of the Promise.all.

```
let queryArray = [];
queryArray.push(User.create([{ name: 'alice' }]));
queryArray.push(Post.create([{ content: 'foo' }]));

Promise.all(queryArray).then(([Users, Posts]) => {
const comments = [
    { content: 'bar', user: Users[0], post: posts[0] }
];   
return Comment.create(comments);
}).catch(Error => {
   console.log("Error: ", Error);
})
```